# Strip #xxx comments except when they occur inside quotes in sed

Tags: sed

How to solve the following problem?
Input

```
hai this is "#test" #this is comment
```

Question:
       How to remove only the comment in shell script. 
       Expected output:

```
hai this is "#test"
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU or FreeBSD `sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(([^"#]|"(\\.|[^\\"])*")*)#.*/\1/' << EOF
heredoc> hi this is "#test" #this is comment
heredoc> this is test # comment with # characters
heredoc> hi this is "\"test" #this is comment as " was escaped earlier
heredoc> EOF
hi this is "#test"
this is test
hi this is "\"test"
```

The idea being to match `#.*` that follows a sequence of either:

- characters other than `"` or `#` (`[^"#"]`)
- or `"..."` quoted string where `...` is a sequence of either:

  - `\x`: backslash followed by any character (`\\.`)
  - or a character other than `"` or `\`.

POSIXly (where there's no *alternation* (`|`) operator ([yet](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528))), you could write it:

```
sed 's/^\(\(\("\(\(\\.\)\{0,1\}[^\"]\)*"\)\{0,1\}[^"#]\)*\)#.*/\1/'
```

There, instead of ERE `(a|b)*`, we use BRE `\(a\{0,1\}b\)*`, that is instead of a sequence of `a` or `b`, we use a sequence of `b` optionally preceded by `a`.

Comment: How does it handle backslash-escaped backslashes? I got a little lost...

Comment: @m. like any other backslash escaped character: with `\\.`

Comment: But then how does `"\\""` work, i guess is what I'm asking. I don't get how `(\\.|[^\"])` reliably handles escaped escapes. I assume it must, but I can't figure on how.

Answer (score 1):

The simplistic answer might be:

```
sed 's/#[^#]*$//g'
```

Which will match `#` followed by one or more 'not `#`' character until the end of line. If you're after something a bit more complex, it'd be worth expanding a bit on specifically what you're after.

Comment: Note that while it works on the OP's sample, it doesn't strip the full comment in `foo # bar # baz`, and wrongly strips it in `"#test with no comment"`

Comment: That's true. The 'right' answer would be to process the quotes and exclude - but personally I think that's getting into the realms of some quite messy patterns, which may be overkill for the OPs use case.